# Getting class from string in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have created a custom class named `PredicateController`.

I need to pass the class of PredicateController which will be called from a framework written in Objc. However, whenever I am using the properties of swift, the same is returning me `<ProjectName>.PredicateController`.

I only need the class name as `PredicateController`.

Is there any workaround in swift to do the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Custom Class: PredicateViewController

import Cocoa

@objc(PredicateViewController)

class PredicateViewController: SCViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        println("Getting called over here ")
    }
}

Accessing via :

            println(NSClassFromString(PredicateViewController.className().componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!))

Comment: I added the answer below. `self` gets you the type as well as being able to wrap it into string. Please accept it as the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Accept the solution if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of a class by using `self` on the class and then simply wrap it into a string, e.g. ...

```
let date = NSDate();
let clazz = NSDate.self
let str = "\(date) is of type \(clazz)"
println(str)
```

Comment: `let clazz = date.className`

Comment: @EricD. Is that still part of Swift 1.2? Because I can neither get `className` nor `dynamicType`.

Comment: Yes, Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.3 ([screenshot of my Playground](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/706e7dcf-5904-4a97-812f-2dcd01e40c00/eaa71a2fff194f34))

Comment: Interesting! Works when importing Cocoa but not with UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.className` on the instance if the class is inheriting from `NSObject`:

```
class PredicateController: NSObject {
    // ...
}
let pc = PredicateController()
let klass = pc.className
let name = klass.componentsSeparatedByString(".")[1]
let str = "\(pc) is of type \(name)"
println(str) // "<__lldb_expr_1398.PredicateController: 0x7fd92b465080> is of type PredicateController"
```

*My answer is a follow-up to @hexagonstar's one. I don't know if it's the proper way of doing this, but it works.*